Android is queueing 'startActivity' if called twice immediately?
Consider this Activity that upon a button press calls startActivity twice. I have no real use case here, I am just trying to understand this scenario in theory.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(__ -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}

I would assume that SecondActivity will behave based on its launchMode; e.g. by default two would be opened, but you can use singleTop/singleInstance/singleTask etc. to modify and limit that behavior.
I cannot find an explanation for the behavior I'm seeing when I call startActivity twice in immediate succession. Android will start the SecondActivity, then wait until it is finished, and only then open a new SecondActivity. I see no change in behavior regardless of the launchMode of SecondActivity.
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("SecondActivity", "Created");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Log.i("SecondActivity", "Back button pressed");
    }
}

Here I press the button to launch SecondActivity, wait 5 seconds, then press the back button. At this time another SecondActivity is created.
2024-04-02 12:15:33.033 11346-11346 SecondActivity I  Created
2024-04-02 12:15:38.850 11346-11346 SecondActivity I  Back button pressed
2024-04-02 12:15:38.895 11346-11346 SecondActivity I  Created

I fear I misunderstand how Android is handling this. I understand there are ways to prevent opening an Activity twice concurrently but this is somehow happening sequentially...
What is happening?
